Error al pasar datos a traves de una API php con Flight
Saludos a todos que tengan un excelente día, escribo para pedir apoyo sobre un asunto, estoy tratando de crear mi primera API usando FlightPHP, pero al llegar a la ruta del método POST, a pesar de que estoy siguiendo el tutorial, a mi forma para aprender aún más, resulta que logro realizar el POST Con las Variables pero las mismas viajan con los valores nulos:
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//conectarnos a la base de datos
Flight::register('db', PDO::class, ['mysql:host=localhost;dbname=api', 'root', '']);

//leer los datos de la base de datos
Flight::route('GET /alumnos', function () {
    $mostarAlumnos= Flight::db()->prepare("select * from alumnos");
    $mostarAlumnos->execute();
    $datos=$mostarAlumnos->fetchAll();
    Flight::json($datos);
});
//registrar informacion en la base de datos
Flight::route('POST /alumnos', function (){

    //defino las variables a enviar
    $nombres=(Flight::request()->data->nombres);
    $apellidos=(Flight::request()->data->apellidos);
    
    //realizo la insersion de los datos
    $insertarAlumnos = Flight::db()->prepare("insert into alumnos(nombres,apellidos) VALUES (?,?)");
    //paso los datos
    $insertarAlumnos->bindParam(1, $nombres); // Corrección aquí
    $insertarAlumnos->bindParam(2, $apellidos); // Corrección aquí
    //ejecuto la sentencia
    $insertarAlumnos->execute();
    //imprimo mensaje de exito
    Flight::jsonp(["Alumno Agregado"]);
    
});

  
Flight::start();

Básicamente me está enviando el array sin datos y no se que estoy haciendo mal porque aparentemente todo esta bien estructurado.
Si me pueden orientar se los agradeceria!.
Feliz dia a todos.

Hola Ivan, si el problema es que los datos llegan nulos, entonces puede que el problema sea el como envias los datos. Por favor, presioná [edit] y agrega en tu pregunta cómo estás enviando los datos a tu endpoint.

Hola.  No se ve qué datos quieres pasar. Revisa los ejemplos de la documentación y aclara tu problema pulsando en [edit].
